# Django Authentication and ReactJS Templates

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have an existing login template served by django templates and it has no react components at all. I have recently integrated ReactJS and have created some routes and components and pages that are completely react. Now I am wondering how to get a user to login through the django template and then be redirected to the ReactJS page afterwards and pass on all the authentication/user information to ReactJS as well.

In Django, I am using the session authentication middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that just allowing an open url to my component something like ".../app/*". But this inside a template in Django as a bundle. What I do is to bind the view with that with LogginRequired from django-brases. So, if I want to se my app, I have to be authenticated. I hope this could help you.